# Keeping Font Relative Size to Object/Graphics/Plot Object upon Resize

Tags: plotting, graphics, text, fonts, scaling

I want to keep the text generated within a graph/plot to remain the same relative to an ***element*** (a disk of size 0.2) of the image upon resize, ***not*** the image itself, while maintaining the original aspect ratio (not having to fix the aspect ratio to 1).  Using a `LayeredGraphPlot` with the following code:

```
Clear[set1, set2]
set1 = Table["" -> " ", {i, 1, 7, 1}];
set1[[1]] = "A" -> "B";
set1[[2]] = "B" -> "C";
set1[[3]] = "D" -> "F";
set1[[4]] = "A" -> "F";
set1[[5]] = "G" -> "B";
set1[[6]] = "H" -> "C";
set1[[7]] = "C" -> "G";

set2 = Table["" -> " ", {i, 1, 7, 1}];
set2[[1]] = "B" -> "A";
set2[[2]] = "B" -> "C";
set2[[3]] = "D" -> "G";
set2[[4]] = "A" -> "F";
set2[[5]] = "G" -> "H";
set2[[6]] = "H" -> "D";
set2[[7]] = "B" -> "G";

LayeredGraphPlot[set1, Bottom,
 VertexLabeling -> True,
 DirectedEdges -> True, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Black, Thickness[0.04], Arrow[#1, .05]} &),
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[{RGBColor[0/225, 0/255, 0/255],
        Thickness[0.02]}],
     RGBColor[255/255, 255/255, 255/255],
     Disk[#1, 0.2],
     RGBColor[0/225, 0/255, 0/255], 
     Style[Text[#2, #1], FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 
      FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]],
     RGBColor[0/225, 0/255, 0/255]} &), 
 PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[{{0.1, 0.8}}],
 PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

I generate an image that makes the internal text labels (based on `FontSize->Scaled`, instead of picking the font size in printer's points) at pretty much the size I want, which happens to be 5% of the total image size.

[image]

However, if I change the data set to

```
set2 = Table["" -> " ", {i, 1, 7, 1}];
set2[[1]] = "B" -> "A";
set2[[2]] = "B" -> "C";
set2[[3]] = "D" -> "G";
set2[[4]] = "A" -> "F";
set2[[5]] = "G" -> "H";
set2[[6]] = "H" -> "D";
set2[[7]] = "B" -> "G";
```

and re-plot, the size of the font, the text labels are still 5% of the total image, but because the image dimensions are different, the text is no longer in the correct scale to the individual disks.

[image]

Is there a way to make the text always be scaled the same to the disk size, rather than the total image size, so upon resize of the image, both disk and text grow/shrink the same amount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, some remark : with Mathematica you don't have to "initialize" lists : you can directly input `set1` and `set2` like this :

```
set1 = {"A" -> "B", "B" -> "C", "D" -> "F", "A" -> "F", "G" -> "B", 
   "H" -> "C", "C" -> "G"};

set2 = {"B" -> "A", "B" -> "C", "D" -> "G", "A" -> "F", "G" -> "H", 
   "H" -> "D", "B" -> "G"};
```

In order the texts and disks scale the same way, you just have to use also `Scaled` inside `Disk` to scale the radius.

I rewrote your code as a function (of course, adjust the parameters in `Scaled` to suit your exact needs.)

```
draw[set_, aspectratio_: 0] := 
 Module[{ar}, 
  ar = If[aspectratio == 0, 
    1./Divide @@ ImageDimensions@Image@LayeredGraphPlot[set, Bottom], aspectratio]; 
  LayeredGraphPlot[set, Bottom, VertexLabeling -> True, 
   DirectedEdges -> True, 
   EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Black, Thickness[0.04], 
       Arrow[#1, .05]} &), 
   VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.02]}], 
       White, Disk[#1, Scaled[{0.1, 0.1/ar}]], Black, 
       Style[Text[#2, #1], FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 
        FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]]} &), 
   PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[{{0.1, 0.8}}], PlotRangePadding -> 0., 
   Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> ar]]
```

By default, you get the default (very close to) aspect ratio of `LayeredGraphPlot`     :

```
draw[set1]
```

[image]

```
draw[set2]
```

[image]

But you can also specify any aspect ratio by adding a second parameter, for example :

```
draw[set2, 2]
```

[image]

Comment: Will this work properly with the `AspectRatio` left unspecified?  This is something I mention at the start of my question, and your code `AspectRatio->1`.

Comment: @iwantmyphd Oops ! Sorry I read too fast ... Yes, there is a problem when this ratio is not 1 but i'll see if there is a workaround. Why don't you want to have this ratio equal to 1 ?

Comment: It's not that an aspect ratio of 1 is bad, I just want it to work for *any* aspect ratio.

Comment: @iwantmyphd Please see my edit.

Comment: @iwantmyphd you have to create the plots, obtain the aspect ratio used by Mathematica and via absolute options and then recreate the plots by adjusting the scaled length for disk in the y direction. Have you actually tried doing that yet?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I actually haven't tried that, and I will, but I'm missing why I actually have to specify the aspect ratio at all.  Isn't there something within `Scaled` that allows for Mathematica to pick the aspect ratio and then change the scale accordingly?

Comment: @iwantmyphd yes. do you want circular disks or not, or will that be another change to your question?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I don't understand : is something wrong with the solution I gave ? or do you just want to do it in a different way ?

Comment: @SquareOne my comment was not addressed to you. I gave the same solution 23 hours ago but he rejected it and I deleted it. The OP does not understand the connection between image sizes and `Scaled` and aspect ratio.

Comment: @SquareOne @MikeHonyechurch You are both correct, I do want circles, and I am also not clear on how `Scaled` and `AspectRatio` are linked.  Based on my reading of those two manual pages, I'm having trouble understanding it.  Implementing your code (verbatim) for some reason is not drawing circles for me at all, I get over-sized ellipses that still change keep a constant font size regardless of resizing.  Perhaps there is something else at play here that I'm not considering.

Comment: @iwantmyphd Can you confirm : by implementing the function `draw` you don't get circles ?? I get perfect circles for any parameters and if i resize the image in the notebook. Please, what is then your config ? (mathematica version and system).

Comment: @SquareOne I have rebooted and now get circles... odd, but solved.  My config is v.9.0.1.0, MBP, OS X 10.6.8.  The font resizes appropriately, which is great, thank you.  I guess the `AspectRatio` problem is a separate issue than this question (?), because for the set1/set2, with an aspect ratio of 1, everything looks fine, but when I load other data sets, I need to tweak the aspect ratio, whereas if Mathematica was allowed to pick it, it looks fine.  I am happy to upvote your answer, and @MikeHoneychurch, if you wish to resubmit your answer, I am happy to accept it since you were 1st. Thanks!

Comment: @iwantmyphd do you or do you not want the "natural" image size and aspect ratio that Mathematica chooses automatically for each plot?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I want the "natural" image aspect ratio, but I am operating under the assumption that I can rescale the image post-operation.

Comment: @iwantmyphd I found a quick way to get the default or natural aspect ratio of `LayeredGraphPlot`. Please see my edit.

Comment: @SquareOne Looks like it works with a few random data sets.  I'll need to check it with a few more to be certain but at this point I'll consider it solved.  Thanks!