# LayeredGraphPlot Vertex Spacing / Edge Length

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, spacing

For anyone who has used `LayeredGraphPlot` (Mma v9), you have probably seen that the vertex spacing is consistent throughout, that vertices have the same minimum unit of spacing in the vertical and horizontal directions.

I know that changing `AspectRatio` will adjust one of the directions with respect to the other, but if I want to keep the existing aspect ratio, but want to space the vertices further apart (*not* resizing the overall graphic).

Without specifying the actual vertex potions using `VertexCoordinateRules` for each vertex, is it possible to change the vertical/horizontal spacing unit?  For instance, if I just want all of the vertices to be spaced twice as far apart from each other in each direction as the default, can this be set?

**UPDATE:**  For a given set a vertices `LayeredGraphPLot` chooses this minimum spacing unit, however, if you change the list of rules, or use a different set of rules (and hence how the vertices are connected), it will redraw it with *different* spacing, even though it could have been done using the spacing from the original set of rules, regardless of if you leave `AspectRatio` and `ImageSize` as free parameters or not.  There may be an algorithm to avoid vertex crowding, but I don't see why the minimum unit spacing couldn't still be set anyway.

Here is an example, note that all of the red lines are the same size, depicting the constant unit dimension between vertices.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**  SquareOne's solution with two different data sets:

`set1 = {"A" -> "B", "B" -> "C", "D" -> "F", "A" -> "F", "G" -> "B", 
  "H" -> "C", "C" -> "G"};`

[image]

`set2 = {"B" -> "A", "B" -> "G", "D" -> "H", "A" -> "F", "G" -> "A", 
   "H" -> "B", "F" -> "G"};`

[image]

You can see, that with the same number of rules in the list (and hence the same number of edges), the same number of vertices, with the vertices being the same size (resizing the images), and the aspect ratios allowed to vary as needed to accommodate the plot, the edgelengths are very different.

**UPDATE 3:** SquareOne's solution has been modified to work for arbitrary datasets, I therefore accept his solution.

Comment: "not resizing the overall graphic" so e.g. `ImageSize->700` can't be a solution. Could you explain why in more details?

Comment: @ybeltukov Let me edit my question to address this.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Another related command  is `Graph` with `GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", LayerSizeFunction -> (1 &), "LeafDistance" -> 1}`. However the scaling of both parameters changes nothing.

Comment: @ybeltukov `GraphLayout` doesn't appear to be a valid command within `LayeredGraphPLot` (this is Mma 9.0.1).

Comment: I mean `Graph[Table[i <-> Mod[i + 1, 5], {i, 12}], GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", LayerSizeFunction -> (1 &), "LeafDistance" -> 1}]`. It works in both V9 and V10.

Comment: I probably miss something ... I don't understand your goal : *"For instance, if I just want all of the vertices to be spaced twice as far apart from each other in each direction as the default"* : if you do so, the size of the image will be exactly twice bigger, so is it not the same that rescaling the image size ?

Comment: @SquareOne Resizing the image will increase the size of ***both*** the edges (vertex spacing) and vertices, and I specified in my question that I ***only*** want to change the edge (vertex spacing) alone.

Comment: Do you want the size of the vertices (the circles in your figure) remains the same ?

Comment: @SquareOne Yes, I'd like the size of the vertices to stay the same.

Comment: @iwantmyphd OK, so for example if we double the vertex spacing in the figure you gave (above in your question), the aspect ratio remains the same, but you want the size of your circles to be 2x smaller, right ? In other words, your question could be also "How do I modify the size of the vertices only" ? Do I understand well ? In that case i think it's quite simple to modify the answer I gave you in your previous [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72481/19960).

Comment: @SquareOne No, I want to keep the vertices' appearance the same.  If we were to do what you suggest, doubling the image size and then shrinking the vertex size, then the ***width*** of the edges would appear larger compared to the vertices.  All I want to do is change the edge ***length***, while keeping the edge width, and the original vertex size the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is closely related to your previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72544/19960) and to the answer I gave you then. They could actually be merged.

#### Edit

As requested, here is a new version of the function which let you change the scale of the edges while keeping the same unit length for any working set.

(I finally managed (not trivial) to get the width and height of the plot produced by the function `LayeredGraphPlot` ; these are needed in order to scale properly every elements in the rendering options);

As a bonus ;) the image size of the plots are now automatically scaled according to the unit length. Any other words you don't need anymore to resize manually the plots for different sets in order to compare them.

```
draw[set_, edgescale_: 1, aspectratio_: 0] :=
 Module[{width, height, ar0, ar, thicknessDisk = 0.18},
  {width, height} = 
   edgescale*(LayeredGraphPlot[set, Bottom, Axes -> False, 
         PlotRangePadding -> None][[1, 1, 1]] // Transpose // (Max@# - Min@#) & /@ # &);
  ar0 = height/width;
  ar = If[aspectratio == 0, ar0, aspectratio];
  LayeredGraphPlot[set, Bottom, VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True, 
   EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Black, Thickness[0.1/width], Arrow[#1, 0.05]} &), 
   VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.04/width]}], White, 
       Disk[#1, Scaled[{thicknessDisk/width, ar0*thicknessDisk/height/ar}]], 
       Black, Style[Text[#2, #1], FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 
        FontSize -> Scaled[0.2/width]]} &), 
   PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[{{0.3/width, 0.8}}], 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0., Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> ar, 
   ImageSize -> 75*(width + 2*thicknessDisk)]]
```

**Tests:**

The example sets :

```
set1 = {"A" -> "B", "B" -> "C", "D" -> "F", "A" -> "F", "G" -> "B", "H" -> "C", "C" -> "G"}; 
set2 = {"B" -> "A", "B" -> "G", "D" -> "H", "A" -> "F", "G" -> "A", "H" -> "B", "F" -> "G"};
```

then put all this in one cell and run :

```
Print["set1 with edge scale = 2:"]; draw[set1, 2]
Print["set1 with edge scale = 1 and aspect ratio = 1:"]; draw[set1, 1, 1]
Print["set1 (default param.):"]; draw[set1]
Print["set2 (default param.):"]; draw[set2]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.  Perhaps the confusion was my using ***vertex spacing*** rather than ***edge length***.  To me, they are equivalent.  I apologize if this was the cause of the confusion.  If they are not equivalent, I'd greatly appreciate understanding how they differ.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, actually my knowledge in Graph Theory and its vocabulary is very poor ;) so i tried to express the problem in other more common words.

Comment: I've now tested this, but it seems that even if I specify `vertexscale`, the edge length varies from dataset to dataset, so it seems that `vertexscale` has units that are unclear to me.  In other words, setting `vertexscale` = 2 produces a different spacing from one data set to the next, when it shouldn't.

Comment: @iwantmyphd Can you give me a simple example with this problem, I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes, I've just uploaded two plots made from your exact code: one with the original rule set, and another with a new rule set that still has the same number of rules (edges), vertices, and vertex size, etc., and you can see the spacing from set1 to set2 differs.  In your code, `vertexspacing` was set to 1, so the spacing in both plots should be the same, but isn't.

Comment: @iwantmyphd Ok, I understand, there might be a solution ... I'll take a look deeper today.

Comment: @iwantmyphd Please see my edit. Hope it works now ;)

Comment: Still testing it, but so far so good.  One question is, which parameter actually adjusts the edge length?

Comment: Good. The second parameter should adjust the edge length. `draw[set1, 2]` will draw the graph with all edges twice longer than in the default `draw[set1]`.